# Delete folder which is in use

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to perform a folder deletion before running Azure DevOps build. My script:

```
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse C:\agent\_work\15
```

The problem which appears is:

> Cannot remove the item at 'C:\agent_work\15' because it is in use.

Can someone give me any advice how it should be handled in correct way?

Comment: There is probably a handle that is open and a process that needs killing before you can delete the folder.  User Process Explorer or ResMon to find which process has a handle on the folder: https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows

Comment: Than you, works as expected :)